# How to align Vuetify snackbar component vertically to the center?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need to align the Vuetify component vertically and horizontally

Versions

vue 2.6.10
vuetify 2.1.10

This is the current code of the component Snackbar

```
<v-snackbar
    class="no-shadow"
    v-model="snackbarShow"
    :color="snackbarType"
    :timeout="snackbarTimeout"
>
  <v-icon class="mr-3">{{ snackbarIcon }}</v-icon>
  <div>{{ snackbarText }}</div>
  <v-btn text icon color="white" @click="snackbarShow = false">
    <v-icon color="white">mdi-close-circle</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-snackbar>
```

Answer (score 3):

v2

```js
<v-snackbar centered />
```

v3

```
<v-snackbar v-model="snackbar" timeout="5000" location="center">
```

Comment: Having that centered property only aligns it horizontally, but not vertically, that is, I stay in the center, but at the bottom of the page

Comment: @JorgeGatica `Positions the snackbar in the center of the screen, (x and y axis).` https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-snackbar/#props

Comment: While it's true that centered should, paired with absolute, be centered vertically... I had problems where using absolute together with centered didn't work. 
So try removing the absolute prop to center it, if it still stays on top / bottom.

Comment: For v3:  <v-snackbar v-model="snackbar" timeout="5000" location="center">

Answer (score -1):

The reason a snackbar is difficult to align vertically is basically because it is not designed to do this. Vuetify is just one implementation of Google's Material Design specification. Personally, I love Vuetify and use it a lot, but remember it's just a component library, so their documentation primarily focuses on ***how*** to use the components, with no guidance on ***which component to use*** or when you ***should*** or ***shouldn't*** use a particular component. That's why I always reference material.io for that information, to make sure I'm not just piecing together ***material components*** in a way that breaks ***material design*** rules.

As you can see here: https://material.io/components/snackbars snackbars are specifically supposed to be at the bottom of the screen.

To get the style you're after, the UI component you want in the Vuetify library is `v-dialog`. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/
At its heart, it just centers a component (usually a card) horizontally and vertically, while providing an easy way to bind its visibility to a prop and even gives you a `hide-overlay` prop. So using that component, you could get the style you're after, pretty much 'out of the box.'
Just make sure that placing a component in the dead center of the UI doesn't make for a bad UX. Material.io has some excellent guidance in picking the right component for the right task: https://material.io/components/dialogs#usage

Comment: I mean, you can still center a snackbar. And it is not even hard, just add the `centered` prop.